# IE-11 is not recognised as Internet explorer browser

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

1. We have .NET Framework 4.5 installed on our server.
2. We tried to add custom.browser file in our application(App_Browser)Folder
3. We tried to install the hot fix as suggested by microsoft NDP40-KB2836939-v3-x86.exe,But the hotfix is for .NET Framework 4.0 and our application is using 4.5

Still we are facing the issue and getting the error "ScriptResource.axd file doesn't support property or method"

These all issues are related to IE-11 not recognised and not supporting JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried installing the hotfix? I believe .NET 4.5 is an in place replacement of .NET 4.0 so it may well be that the same fix will apply to both. Especially given the nature of the fix I would expect it to apply properly.

Comment: Chris Thanks for information.But we are having .net 4.5 framework(mandatory for our application) so when we are trying to install Hot Fix KB2836939v3 We are getting message as "KB2836939v3 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer".

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931600/internet-explorer-11-gives-script-error-in-pagerequestmanager-js may be of interest but given it was the 2nd hit on google for your error message I assume you've seen it...

Comment: Have you consider this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

Comment: Have you consider the solution proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931600/internet-explorer-11-gives-script-error-in-pagerequestmanager-js

Comment: Thanks Dalorzo,But we already tried this

Comment: @Chris, We cannot add metatag to directly force the application to run in IE-10(Due to application constraint)

Comment: @Code Uniquely,we can apply meta tag to force our application to run in IE-10, it should be in IE-11 only

Comment: @Code Uniquely,we cannot apply meta tag to force our application to run in IE-10, it should be in IE-11 only – user3169255

Comment: You still might want to consider the work around while you wait until they fix the codebase?

Comment: @Code Uniquely,we cannot add metatag to force of our application to work in IE-10